# custom image upload option in jodit editor by laravel

Tags: laravel, upload, jodit

I'm coding the **editor** in the `Laravel` framework and implementing the `Jodit` library.
I want to add an **upload** for the **editor**. The problem is that the **upload** does not work for the **editor**. My codes are as follows.

[image]

my route

```
Route::prefix('')->namespace('Web')->name('')->group(function() {
    Route::post('/upload', 'UploadController@index' )->name('index');
});
```

my UploadController.php

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $file->move( storage_path('uploads') , imagetrim($file->getClientOriginalName()) );
    }
}
```

my blade:

```
<textarea name="content" class="editor"></textarea>
```

my js:

```
var editor = new Jodit('.editor', {
    textIcons: false,
    iframe: false,
    iframeStyle: '*,.jodit_wysiwyg {color:red;}',
    height: 800 ,
    defaultMode: Jodit.MODE_WYSIWYG,
    observer: {
        timeout: 100
    },
    commandToHotkeys: {
        'openreplacedialog': 'ctrl+p'
    },
    uploader: {
        url: '/upload'
    },
    });
});
```

Error Console:

```
1. Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: resp is undefined.
2. Post : http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload :> Status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

But I am not getting a good result, I can't upload, and the photo is not uploaded to the folder `storage/uploads`. It says that `resp` is not defined and you need to add it. What code should I enter for it (`resp`) to be uploaded?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use file manager or other features, you have to buy it. Because it is a paid program.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).